# Disable/TurnOff Angular ESLint "Async pipe results should not be negated"

Tags: angular, eslint

After running ng link i saw

```
/home/lans/projects/crm/new_frontend/src/app/modules/customers/list/list.component.html
  228:12  warning  Async pipe results should not be negated. Use (observable | async) === (false || null || undefined) to check its value instead  @angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async
```

but code is pretty much:

```
listLoading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

and

```
<mat-paginator *ngIf="!(service.listLoading$ | async)"></mat-paginator>
```

how to disable warn / errors like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit ***.eslintrc.json*** in root of project and add ***5 row from end*** to your project

**possible variants is "off" / "warn" / "error"**

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "crm",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "crm",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```